# Index out of range when creating new combined slice of structs from 3 individual slices (one slice for each struct property)

Tags: for-loop, go, struct

I have a struct like this:

```
type Headers struct {
    header            string
    valueFromCalculation    string
    value            float64
}
```

I need have three slices with the values for each of these:

```
var headerLabels []string
var values []float64
var valueFromCalculation []string


[January February March April May June July August September TOTAL]
[175 167 148 142 125 114 130 120 30 1151]
[15% 15% 13% 12% 11% 10% 11% 10% 3%]
```

Now I want to create a new slice of Headers by combining these. There is one issue, that I believe i'm solving - **the length of the valueFromCalcuation is 1 less than the rest of the slices**

To create the new slice I want to do this:

```
sliceOfHeaders := []*Headers{}

for i := 0; i <= len(headerLabels); i++ {

headerEntry := new(Headers)

headerEntry.header = headerLabels[i]
headerEntry.value = values[i]

if i == len(headerLabels) {
    headerEntry.valueFromCalculation = ""
} else {
    headerEntry.valueFromCalculation = valueFromCalculation[i]
}

sliceOfHeaders = append(sliceOfHeaders, headerEntry)
}
```

**It is throwing the below error**:

"panic: runtime error: index out of range"

How can this be?

I'm accounting for the issue of the index with the valueFromCalculation length being one less than the other struct properties

Here you can see output from before I want to start my loop:

```
header --> [January February March April May June July August September TOTAL]
value --> [175 167 148 142 125 114 130 120 30 1151]
valueFromCalculation --> [15% 15% 13% 12% 11% 10% 11% 10% 3%]
header length --> 10
value length --> 10
valueFromCalculation length --> 9
```

**Please can someone help me here? I can't see what i'm doing wrong**

I'm accounting for the length of the 3rd property being 1 less than the rest

Comment: you're not taking into account the extra element, because `len(headerLabels)` is past the last index of `valueFromCalculation`. You're for loop is also incorrect, you can't use `<=` or you're going to get the length as the last index.

Comment: But would saying that if the index is at the last place, set the valueFromCalculation to "" not solve this? Else use the index?

Comment: You’re not saying it’s at the last place, you’re saying it’s one past the last place. The last index is len - 1,  not len.

Comment: @MassiveOwl, the last index is `len-1`, which is why a basic for loop is always written as `for i := 0; i < len; i++`

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was a stupid and fundermental error on my part

Comment: "There are 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are looping one index too long on headerLabels.

Try changing
`i <= len(headerLabels)` to `i < len(headerLabels)`

And

`if i == len(headerLabels)` to `if i == len(headerLabels) - 1`

Comment: Those are the hardest mistakes to spot in one’s own code.